# Is MySQL server installed by default?

Tags: 11.04, server, mysql

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 11.04. Since I want to work with a MySQL server on this machine I see, that if I enter `mys` in the terminal and hit TAB it completes to `mysql`. But if I do `mysql -u` it says

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I thought "maybe I have to start the server first", so I tryed

```
/etc/init.d/mysql
```

Unfortunately bash tells me

```
bash: /etc/init.d/mysql: No such file or directory
```

If I do `locate mysql` I get a whole bunch of directories and files with mysql in it. So it raises the question: **Is MySQL pre-installed on Ubuntu 11.04 or do I have to install it manually? And if it is already installed, how do I configure/start the server, since the way I know how to start a MySQL server on Ubuntu `/etc/init.d/mysql` doesn't seem to work?**

I got the feeling that I miss something and I'll be glad if someone could give me a hint.

Thanks!!

Comment: you probably have mysql client installed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The package that needs to be installed for the MySQL server is named `mysql-server`. If `/etc/init.d/mysql` does not exist, the MySQL server is not installed. After installing it using `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`, it will be started automatically (after the installation and on startup).

Ubuntu has migrated from traditional initscripts to Upstart. If you run `/etc/init.d/mysql [action]` you'll get a notice.

To stop MySQL, run:

```
sudo stop mysql
```

To start it:

```
sudo start mysql
```